# Matlab function/script to list the paths of all subdirectories (folders only) recursively

Tags: matlab, recursion, directory

I need to recursively list all folders in a directory.

e.g. In Z drive, running it should produce something like this:

```
Z:\

Z:\Home\

Z:\Home\A Folder\

Z:\Home\A Folder\testing\

Z:\Home\B Folder\

Z:\Home\C Folder\

Z:\Home\C Folder\test2\

Z:\Test 3\
```

Also, bonus question, afterward how can I only list the children folders?

e.g.

```
Z:\Home\A Folder\ < This would be removed

Z:\Home\A Folder\testing\  <This would be kept
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`genpath`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/genpath.html) function for this. From the docs:

> p = genpath(folderName) returns a path string that includes folderName
>   and multiple levels of subfolders below folderName

Comment: @towi I don't think that applies with regard to official documentation, anyone with Matlab has this article on their hard drive by just typing `doc genpath` and there isn't really any explanation to give in this situation either because the function takes not parameters aside from the base path and does exactly what is asked for.

Comment: @towi: In my opinion this answer is not a "link-only answer" because the text of the answers everything, the link is not essential.

Comment: @Daniel You are right. It's not a link only answer, I apologize. But it could greatly be improved by excerpting the relevant information from that site.

Comment: @towi Added a quote from the docs, but in this case I really don't think it's needed. The question was is there a function that does X, then answer is yes. There is nothing tricky about implementing it even.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the suggestion, seems to be the right function for the job! Unfortunately when running on a directory the size I currently have it takes an extremely long time to run, perhaps understandably (about 2000 folders). I will have to tackle this bit by bit

Answer (score 4):

To only keep the children (deepest-level) folders: apply [`genpath`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/genpath.html) as in [Dan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24490969/2586922); convert to a cell array of strings with [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html); and remove each string that is a prefix of some other ([`strmatch`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/strmatch.html) detects prefixes):

```
p = genpath('C:\Users\lmendo\Documents'); %// argument is base folder
folders = regexp(p,';','split'); %// split into strings
folders = folders(1:end-1); %// remove last element (it's empty)
valid = false(size(folders));
for n = 1:numel(folders)
    valid(n) = numel(strmatch(folders(n),folders))==1; %// 1 means the folder is 
    %// only a prefix of itself
end
children_folders = folders(valid);
```

Comment: @KAE Thanks! Corrected